# Linux - Make Hotspot without bridging internet access with secondary usb wi-fi dongle

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

Situation:
Raspberry Pi 3(Single board mini PC) with debian based distro (Raspbian), with 2 wi-fi cards, one internal (wlan0), other external (wlan1), in the internal receiving internet from my home router.

What i want:
The other wi-fi card (wlan1 - the sb external one) make a connection between certain devices that don't require internet access (ESP8266 Devices) in my case and the Raspberry Pi, so it will create a access point / hotspot

But how can i archieve that?

How can i configure a without-internet-access hotspot within wlan1?

Comment: Just use `hostapd`? Setting up routed or bridged Internet access is actually extra work.

Comment: @DanielB Should I use dhcp server too?

Comment: That of course depends on your requirements. I don't know if those modules even have a DHCP client.

Comment: Do you need to access the IoT devices from your regular network? Or is it enough if software running on the Pi can access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is a tad lengthy.

1. Use *hostapd* to create a hotspot on *wlan1*. There are guides on how to do this all over the Internet, you can find any one you like. You may omit the statement *bridge=br0* as per Daniel B's suggestion.
2. Now you can give your interface an IP address, and bring it up:

   ```
    ip addr add 192.168.1.111/24 dev wlan1
    ip link set dev wlan1 up
   ```

where *192.168.1.111* is an address **outside** your router DHCP pool, but within the same subnet.

3. Now we have to decide on a range of IP addresses for the clients of your hotspot. This is necessary **not** because of DHCP-reasons, but because of **routing** (see the next bullet). Choose a small subnet of your main LAN which is **not** used by your main router. For instance, if the router distributes IP addresses in the range *192.168.1.2-192.168.1.100*, you may use something like *192.168.1.112/28*, which includes all addresses in the range *192.168.1.112-192.168.1.127*.
4. Now add the **all-important** route:

   ```
    ip route add 192.168.1.112/28 dev wlan1
   ```

This instructs your kernel to send packets for your wifi clients through the correct interface, **not** through your standard interface *wlan0* where you *already* have a rule

```
    ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0
```

which comes from your DHCP. Let me repeat it, because it is important: the first route takes precedence over the second one because it is more specific, so that your kernel will know how to reach your wifi clients by using the *wlan1* interface.

6. Now you need to setup *dnsmasq* to work on interface *wlan1* to dish out addresses in the range *192.168.1.112/28*; use the following */etc/dnsmasq.conf* file:

   ```
    domain-needed
    bogus-priv
    dhcp-authoritative
    interface=wlan1
    server=8.8.8.8
    server=8.8.4.4
    expand-hosts
    domain=YourLanName.lan
    dhcp-range=192.168.1.112,192.168.1.127,12h
    dhcp-option=3,192.168.1.1
    dhcp-host=4C:E6:76:00:11:22,PC_NAME,192.168.1.119,12h
   ```

which should be self-explanatory. The next-to-the-last line instructs *dnsmasq* to pass as the gateway **not** the IP of the machine on which *dnsmasq* is running, but the IP address of the *true* router/gateway of your LAN. If you do not want the wifi clients to be able to reach the Internet, you may skip the next-to-last line. Start dnsmasq,

```
     systemctl start dnsmasq
```

I presume you are on systemd, otherwise the above should be replaced by

```
    service dnsmasq start
```

The last line shows you how to dish out reserved (=static) addresses. If you wish to assign to one of your wifi clients an IP address outside the *192.168.1.112/28* range, you can do it, just remember to instruct the kernel where that address can be found: for instance,

```
    ip route add 192.168.1.200/32 dev wlan1
```

7. Remember to allow IPv4 traffic through your interfaces,

   ```
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   ```

and to MASQUERADE your traffic,

```
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This last command assures that all traffic leaving the *wlan0* interface appears to have originated from your RPI, which in turn means that your clients will get the replies to their queries; do not worry about keeping track of which returning packets belongs to the RPI and which to one of the clients, the kernel does that automagically for you.

8. Lastly, we have allowed only IP traffic between *wlan0* and *wlan1* (this is the meaning of IPv4-forwarding), which leaves out Layer-2 protocols such as ARP. Should you wish to make up for this deficiency, you can use [proxy-arp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_ARP):

   ```
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/wlan0/proxy_arp
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/wlan1/proxy_arp
   ```

Comment: I'm quite sure the additional interface and the bridge aren't required. The AP network will simply appear as a regular network adapter to the system. And even if you have the bridge, it also appears as a network adapter to the system, even if it has only a single member.

Comment: Hm. I’ve used hostapd (on OpenWrt) without bridges for over 7 years now. Granted, some non-standard WiFi drivers might require additional setup, but anything even remotely modern should work “as is”.

Comment: @DanielB Ok, I modified my post as per your comments.